# Striping unnecessary tags when printing into a textarea in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

Friends, I would like to print the contents in a text area named `text`. I know about the `window.print()` function, however using that only allows me to print the whole web page. What I need, though, is to print the contents of that specific textarea only...

My code is given below:

```
<?php 
$sq="SELECT * FROM $db->db_schema.visit_reg where patient_id=$user_id and complaint_id=$complaint_id";
$result=$db->query($sq);
echo "<textarea name='text' rows='4' cols='47' >";
echo $result[0]['prescription']; 
echo "</textarea>"; 
?>
```

To reiterate, I'd like to print the contents of that textarea only, not the whole web page.

Answer (score 1):

you can use php strip tags, it will remove php and html tags from given strings.

```
echo strip_tags($result[0]['prescription']); //it will print text only.
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php